# Unknown URL Parameter got indexed on Google

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I already checked my site URL source code and I can't find any URL parameter like in screenshot. And my site is safe from malware, I already test it with sucuri.

I'm using yoast plugin so already auto set canonical.

[image: Unknown url paramter]

- where did the URL parameter come from?
- should I request remove directory `/page/` in webmaster console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discounting that the problem is internal to your website, then it would potentially only take another (malicious) site to link to your site with these "anti-keyword rich" URL parameters for these to be picked up by Google and potentially indexed. (Although you don't actually state whether you are seeing these URLs in the SERPs, or just in Google's Search Console?)

By simply appending a URL parameter to most URLs will still result in a valid 200 OK response.

You should at the very least ensure you have the correct canonical tag set in the `head` section of your page (which you say is already present), so these spurious URL parameters do not appear in the SERPs.

> should i request remove directory /page/ in webmaster console ?

Well, that depends on what these URLs return. If they are simply part of a paginated series then possibly - although that naturally depends on the content.

If you have determined that this `hl=` URL parameter plays no part on your site, then you could perhaps force a 404 for these URLs. If using Apache, then you could do something like the following in `.htaccess` using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^hl=
RewriteRule ^page/\d+/ - [R=404]
```

**UPDATE:** If these URLs are being returned in the organic search results then you could perhaps return a `410 Gone` instead of a 404. This will send a stronger message to search engines to drop these results from the SERPs quicker. To do this, change the `R=404` flag in the above `RewriteRule` directive to `G`. ie. `RewriteRule ^page/\d+/ - [G]`

Comment: My url with that parameter all indexed by google total 500++
And for example /page/28/ has 3 different /page/28/?hl=blablabla indexed in google
i'm sure seo plugin add correct canonical is /page/28/

Comment: When you say they are "indexed in google" - are they being returned in organic search results? Or are you checking with a `site:` search (which tends to return additional URLs). If these URLs are being returned in the SERPs then, instead of returning a 404 for these URLs, you could perhaps return a `410 Gone` instead - this should send a stronger signal to Google to drop these results. I'll update my answer.